# Using an angular template and links

Tags: jquery, angularjs, gsap

I'm a bit of an angular baby, but I've been going through this tutorial to make some nifty looking nav buttons.

http://onehungrymind.com/build-super-smooth-rollover-angularjs-greensock-timelinelite/

However, I'm trying to figure out the simplest, most efficient way to make each circle have an individual unique link inside of the top div.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's something that barely works. Run the snippet below.

It's not the best code ever written, but perhaps it'll provide some inspiration. I basically rolled my own smooth button thingy. It's not super pretty, and could use a lot of work, but I'm out of time :) The way I added links was to insert foreign objects during the mouseover and mouseout event.

I'm pretty sure the tween max libraries uses svg too.

Anyway, maybe you can draw inspiration from this. If this is a waste of space, let me know and I'll delete it.

```js
var app = angular.module("testApp", []);

app.directive('smoothButton', function () {
    var linker = function (scope, element, attrs) {
        var colors = ["red", "green", "yellow", "blue"]
        var circles = [];
        var links = [];
        var speed = 1; //ms
        var size = 45;
        var x = 150;
        var y = 150;

        for (var i = 3; i >= 0; i--) {
            addCircle(element, x, y, size, i);
        }

        var grow = function (size, finalSize, idx) {
            var interval = setInterval(function () {
                var circle = circles[idx];

                if (size >= finalSize) {
                    clearInterval(interval);
                    addLink(element,
                    x - 20,
                    180 - (finalSize * 1.5));

                }
                size += 1;
                circle.setAttribute("r", size);

            }, speed);
        }

        var shrink = function (size, finalSize, idx) {
            var interval = setInterval(function () {
                var circle = circles[idx];

                if (size <= finalSize) {
                    clearInterval(interval);
                    for (link in links) {
                        if (links[link].parentNode) links[link].parentNode.removeChild(links[link]);
                    }

                }
                size -= 1;
                circle.setAttribute("r", size);

            }, speed);
        }

            function getFinalSize(size, idx) {
                var result = size;
                return result + (result * (Math.log(Math.abs(idx - 3) + 1.2)));
            }

            function addCircle(element, x, y, size, i) {
                var circle = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "circle");
                circle.setAttribute("cx", x);
                circle.setAttribute("cy", y);
                circle.setAttribute("r", size);
                circle.setAttribute("fill", colors[i]);

                element.parent().append(circle);

                if (i == 0) {
                    circle.addEventListener("mouseover", function () {
                        for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                            grow(size, getFinalSize(size, j), j);
                        }
                    });

                }
                //last circle only
                if (i == 3) {
                    circle.addEventListener("mouseout", function () {
                        for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                            shrink(getFinalSize(size, j), size, j);
                        }
                    });
                }
                circles.push(circle);
            }


            function addLink(element, x, y) {

                var fo = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "foreignObject");
                fo.setAttribute("width", "50");
                fo.setAttribute("height", "50");
                fo.setAttribute("x", x);
                fo.setAttribute("y", y);

                var body = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml", "body");
                body.innerHTML = "<a href='#' style='background:white;font-size:25px;'> test </a>";

                fo.appendChild(body);
                element.parent().append(fo);
                links.push(fo);

            }
    }

    return {
        link: linker,
        restrict: 'E'
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="testApp">
    <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 1000 300">
        <smooth-button></smooth-button>
    </svg>
</div>
```